# Rate of change of the position with respect to the distance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

In my textbook, there is a theorem which states that if the position vector of a body is
$\overrightarrow r$ and the covered distance is $s$ such that $\overrightarrow r$ is a function of $s$ then $$\frac{d\overrightarrow r}{ds} = \widehat t$$
where $\widehat t$ is a unit vector which is tangential to the trajectory of the body.

My question is: How can we rigorously prove this?
The textbook uses this theorem to prove that the velocity vector $\overrightarrow v$ of a moving body is always tangential to the trajectory of the body.
$$\overrightarrow v = {d \overrightarrow r\over dt} = {d \overrightarrow r\over ds} × {ds\over dt} = {ds\over dt} \widehat t$$
So the direction of the velocity vector $\overrightarrow v$ is in the direction of the unit vector $\widehat t$ which is tangential to the trajectory of the body

Update:
At least if you are going to downvote the question, add anything helpful like stating what was actually wrong with the question or whether it was asked before or not because I searched a lot and found nothing, instead of just adding a downvote and leaving.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I already stated my question. "How can we rigorously prove this?" How to prove that ${d\overrightarrow{r} \over ds} = \widehat t$?

Comment: You cannot prove a definition.

Comment: This is not a definition. It's a theorem.

Comment: This is not something we can take as an axiom or a definition. To state that the rate of change of the position vector with respect to the distance is always a unit vector tangential to the trajectory can never be a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf r:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be the continuously-differentiable vector-valued function such that $\mathbf r(t)$ is the position vector of the particle at time $t$. The distance traveled in between $t=t_1$ and $t=t_2$ is defined to be

$$\Delta(t_1,t_2) := \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \Vert\mathbf r'(t)\Vert dt$$

Let $[a,b]$ be a time interval over which $\Vert \mathbf r'(t)\Vert >0$.  On this interval, the function $D(t) := \Delta(a,t)$, which gives the distance traveled since time $t=a$, is strictly increasing and continuously differentiable with derivative $D'(t) = \Vert \mathbf r'(t)\Vert$.

Let $\sigma:D[a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be the reparameterization function such that $\sigma\big(D(t)\big)=t$. This function is guaranteed to exist because $D$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$.  It is also continuously differentiable with derivative $\sigma'(s) = 1/D'\big(\sigma(s)\big)$ via the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Define the function $\mathbf R : D[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ given by $\mathbf R = \mathbf r \circ\sigma$, which gives the position of the particle as a function of how far it has traveled since time $t=a$. To conclude the proof, note that

$$\mathbf R'(s) = \mathbf r'\big(\sigma(s)\big)  \sigma'(s) = \frac{\mathbf r'\big(\sigma(s)\big)}{D'\big(\sigma(s)\big)}$$

The right hand side can immediately be seen to be a unit vector, since $D'(t) = \Vert \mathbf r'(t)\Vert$.  It is also clearly parallel to the velocity vector $\mathbf r'$.

---

Note that $\mathbf R'(s)$ is usually written (in a common abuse of notation) $\frac{d\mathbf r}{ds}$, and that $\sigma(s)$ is the time which corresponds to a travel distance of $s$ since $t=a$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether this is rigorous enough for you, but it satisfies me to say ...

If A and B are two points on the body's trajectory, then
$$\Delta \vec r =  \vec {r_A} - \vec {r_B}$$
in which $\vec r$ is the body's position vector.
Now consider $\frac{\Delta \vec{r}}{\Delta s}$.

Provided that the trajectory doesn't bend sharply, then as $\Delta s$, the distance along the trajectory between A and B, approaches zero,
$$\Delta s = |\Delta \vec r|$$
So $\frac{\Delta \vec{r}}{\Delta s}$ is the unit vector in the direction $\Delta \vec r$, that is in the direction of the tangent to the trajectory.

Comment: I agree with your approach, because this theorem seems really intuitive that's why I was asking for a more rigorous proof.

Comment: Like you, I'll be interested to see other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is almost trivial.
But I don't know if this is rigorous enough from a mathematical point of view.

The distance $ds$ is defined to be the absolute norm of the position difference $d\vec{r}$:
$$ds=|d\vec{r}|$$
Therefore the differential quotient $\frac{d\vec{r}}{ds}$

- is a vector of length $1$
  (since $\left|\frac{d\vec{r}}{ds}\right|=\frac{|d\vec{r}|}{ds}=\frac{ds}{ds}=1$)
- and has the same direction as $d\vec{r}$

In other words: $\frac{d\vec{r}}{ds}$ is a unit vector tangential to the trajectory.